# How to pass argument value from Xcode Bot to UI test code

Tags: xcode-bots, xcode9.4

I am using Xcode 9.4.1, trying to set up Xcode server and bots. During the process, I am facing one issue where I am not able to pass Environment variable value to UI test code.

Could anyone please guide me to achieve solutions.

Thanks,
Selva

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Hi @R Balasubramanian,
Sorry for late reply.

`guard let emailID = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["USER_ID"], let pswd = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["USER_PSWD"], let env = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TEST_ENV"] else {
            return
        }`

Same code is working fine when I am adding environment variable in "Edit Scheme -> Test -> Arguments".

Thanks, Selva